Question on the 1st-order Taylor expansion of $f(x + o(\epsilon))$ and embedded little-o notation.
Suppose I have a quantity $x + o(\epsilon)$, where $o(\epsilon)$ is the little-o notation representing some continuous function satisfying $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{o(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}=0$. Let $f(\cdot)$ be an analytic function. I know that $f(x + h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + o(h)$. But can $f(x + o(\epsilon))$ be expanded in the same way? Wouldn't I get something like $f(x + o(\epsilon)) = f(x) + f'(x)o(\epsilon) + o(o(\epsilon)) = f(x) + o(\epsilon) + o(o(\epsilon))$? Am I mis-using notation here, or does $o(o(\epsilon))$ have an actual mathematical meaning, as some sort of embedded little-o notation? Mathematically, $o(o(\epsilon))$ is some function satisfying $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{o(o(\epsilon))}{o(\epsilon)}=0$, but this doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Your expansion makes perfect sense. However, we can note that a function which is $o(o(\epsilon))$ is also just $o(\epsilon)$, as $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{o(o(\epsilon))}{\epsilon} = \left(\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{o(o(\epsilon))}{o(\epsilon)}\right)\left(\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{o(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}\right) = 0 \cdot 0 = 0$$
So we can simplify further that $$f(x+o(\epsilon))=f(x)+f'(x)o(\epsilon)+o(o(\epsilon))=f(x)+o(\epsilon)+o(\epsilon)=f(x)+o(\epsilon) $$

This makes sense! Thank you.
